# Trigger PHP process from display:block

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am trying to implement a hit counter within a news archive system.

The articles are displayed with a lightbox style jQuery plugin. This means that all the articles are loaded with the rest of the page, but are set to have display:hidden, until the relevant entry has been clicked on.

So, I can't have the PHP to increment the counter simply embedded in the page, and in a search to find something to trigger the counter, all I could think of was this change to display:block.

I am open to any suggestions, although I am more experienced with simple jQuery, I have a hunch AJAX may be needed here?

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can offer, and let me know if any other information would be useful.

***Sorry, but the restrictions where I am currently working mean I only have IE6 at my disposal. So I can't comment on anyone's answers...this is the only way I think I can reply.***

**Response:**

Thanks for everyone's fast responses. I don't think I can use plain jQuery as the system will be on an intranet and need to record the total number of visits across the network, therefore I don't think cookies would be sufficient.

I am going to attempt the load() function suggested by Bradley - a lot simpler than I thought it would be...feeling a little silly now.

Will update as to how I get on :)

**Update:**

I am trying to implement the load() function, with no success. The lack of firebug is also hindering by debugging.

Can anyone see what might be wrong with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#<?php echo $row->articleid; ?>link').click(function() {
    alert("some encouraging text<?php echo $row->articleid; ?>");
    $('#<?php echo trim($row->articleid); ?>target').load("/hitcount.php?articleid=<?php echo $row->articleid; ?>");
});
</script>

<div id="<?php echo trim($row->articleid); ?>link">Click2</div><br />
<div id="<?php echo trim($row->articleid); ?>target"></div>
```

**Embarrassing Update:**
...all that was wrong was the file path.

Comment: Yep ajax is what you want. But jQuery has strong ajax support.

Comment: Bradley's idea is the way to go. Just have the `.load()` action call your script that pulls in the article and displays it. That way, you can increment the counter as the article is required on demand.

Answer (score 2):

Just a simple hit counter? No feedback on user info?

```
$('#result').load('ajax/counter.php');
```

Edit

```
$('#somediv').click(function() {
    $('#result').load('ajax/counter.php');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need Ajax, Just a javascript variable that gets incremented on any onchange event you place on each html input / dropdown / etc..., Then onsubmit, pass that javascript variable.

Comment: You would require ajax if you want to record the data though. Otherwise it would only be available to the client. Unless you stored it in a cookie. Then read the cookie next time the user change page.. or IF the user changes page.

Comment: This could be easily tempered with, not really secured at all.

Comment: From what I read, he is only recording a counter, not having information about the transaction, unless I missed that part of the question. And as always dealing with Javascript, even with Ajax post, both can be tempered with. Doesn't take much for me to randomly send you info through a next loop of GET's, and your controller will be collecting incorrect data. @OliverMGrech

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, ajax would help you here. You can bind to the click event on whatever navigation item switches the article to block display, and have it dispatch something to a click counter script.

```
<a href='#article-1' class='display-article'>display article 1</a>
<a href='#article-2' class='display-article'>display article 2</a>

<div id='article-1' style='display:none;'>article 1</div>
<div id='article-2' style='display:none;'>article 2</div>

<script>
$(function() {
  $('a.display-article').on('click', function(event) {
    var article_id = $(this).attr('href');
    $(article_id).show(); // show the actual article
    // and send the ajax request to the processor
    $.get('/scripts/track-click.php', { article_id: article_id }, function(data) {
      alert('article tracking complete!'
    });
  });
});
```